# Anchor links from external pages don't work when using jQuery smooth scrolling code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not a JS developer, and I'm using Bootstrap to build a one-page site with anchor links.

I'm using whatever bits and pieces of JS code I find for some necessary features, such as adding smooth scrolling to the anchor links, with top offset because I'm using a fixed/sticky menu.

While it's a one-page website, I'm using Privacy and Terms as separate pages.

This is the code I'm using for the anchor links on the homepage. I think it's a mix of JS and jQuery. It works well and the way I want.

```
 $('.navbar a, .smooth-scroll-contact').on('click', function(event) {

    /* Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior */
    if (this.hash !== "") {

        /* Prevent default anchor click behavior */     
        event.preventDefault();

        /* Store hash */
        var hash = this.hash;

        /* Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll. */
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 70
        }, 800, function(){    

            /* Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior). */
            if (history.pushState) {
                history.pushState(null, null, hash);
            }
            else {
                window.location.hash = hash;
            } 
        });

    } // End if

  });
```

While it works fine on the homepage, it prevents the menu links to open on the Privacy and Terms pages. It doesn't do anything when clicking the menu links there. It doesn't go to the homepage or any of the anchor links there.

This is the error that appears in the Console when clicking on the menu links, while on the Privacy or Terms page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (custom.js:39)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.v.handle (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
```

The 39th line is `scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 70`.

I searched for this error and tried to apply some fixes that I found, but they didn't work for me or I didn't know how to implement them correctly for this particular code.

Additional notes:

- If I remove the smooth scrolling code, the problem is solved;
- The `custom.js` file, where the code is found, is loaded before `</body>`;
- jQuery is the first script loaded.

If you need more info, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to find a solution after more research. Here's the new code, in case someone else will encounter the same issue:

```
$('a[href*="#"]')
// Remove links that don't actually link to anything
.not('[href="#"]')
.not('[href="#0"]')
.on('click', function(event) {   

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {

        // Store hash
        var hash = this.hash;

        // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
        // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
        // - 70 is the offset/top margin
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 70
        }, 800, function() {

            // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior), without jumping to hash
            if (history.pushState) {
                history.pushState(null, null, hash); 
            } else {
                window.location.hash = hash;
            } 
        });
        return false;    
    } // End if
});
```

`event.preventDefault();` seems to have been the problem, so it was removed. `return false;` was added.

Also, as a bonus, here's a code that allows smooth scrolling with offset to anchor links from external pages:

```
$(window).on("load", function () {

    var urlHash = window.location.href.split("#")[1];

    if (urlHash &&  $('#' + urlHash).length) {

        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#' + urlHash).offset().top - 70
        }, 800);
    }
});
```